# Magento 1.8.1 limitation for creation of stores, products and categories

Tags: magento-1.8, product, category, store-view, server

I have *Magento 1.8.1* with 5 websites, 40 store group and 2 store views for each store groups, which is working but I am getting it is slow.

Now I need to create over 500 store groups and 2 store views for each store groups(1000) on this.

My Question are :

1. What is the limit of creating store groups, views, products, categories.?
2. If I provide a huge server than can I add more store groups, views and all?
3. What you suggest about creating 500 store groups.?

Comment: If I may ask, what is the goal of having that many stores? What is the major difference between each store?

Comment: We have architecture where main admin provide an store to sub admin.